# VS2008 C++ can't seem to inherit const overloaded method

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, constants, overloading

I was just surprised to find that the following does not compile in VS2008.
The compiler complains that it cannot convert parameter 1 from const int to int& thus demonstrating that it is failing to look at the available method in the Base class.

Is there a good reason for this or is it a deficiency not found in other compilers?

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void doIt(int& v){cout << "Base NonConst v=" << v << endl;}
    virtual void doIt(const int& v) const {cout << "Base Const v=" << v << endl;}
};

struct Child : public Base
{
    virtual void doIt(int& v){cout << "Child NonConst v=" << v << endl;}    
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i = 99;
    const int& c_i = i;

    Child sc;
    sc.doIt(i);
    sc.doIt(c_i);
}
```

This compiles and works as expected if I remove the single overridden method in the Child class or if I access the child class through a Base pointer (or of course if I override both methods in the child class).

However overriding one and not the other method seems to hide the un-overridden Base class method when accessing directly from the Child class or a Child class pointer.

What the hell? Am I missing something?

Comment: When looking up a member name in a class, if the class declaration has a member of that name, then base classes aren't examined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error you are receiving will happen in every compiler (including gcc, msvc 2013, etc..)

`no matching function for call to ‘Child::doIt(const int&)’ sc.doIt(c_i);`

That is the problem. You are overriding the function `doIt` and only providing one override when the parent class has two. It won't search the parent class since you are overriding it.

You should provide both overrides:

```
struct Child : public Base
{
    virtual void doIt(int& v){cout << "Child NonConst v=" << v << endl;}    
    virtual void doIt(const int& v) const { Base::doIt(v);}
};
```

OR you can also do a `using` statement like so (C++11):

```
struct Child : public Base
{
    virtual void doIt(int& v){cout << "Child NonConst v=" << v << endl;}  

    using Base::doIt;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I see, so this is to do with method overloading in general (not just the particular const overload in my example). I must say that it is disappointing that the standard allows this to be the case rather than dictating that full member signatures should be resolved. I'm even more disappointed that this hasn't changed in C++11. Care to comment as to why? Thanks again

Comment: @OldSchool Why? Because A) This is the saver default: no need to check all private functions in all base classes. B) With 'using' you can get the other behavior; if the other behavior had been default, there would have been no way to get the hiding behavior.